# HIVE converting unix timestamp for calculation

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to perform subtraction among timestamps and would like to convert the timestamps in forms that can be converted to minutes.

I used regexp_replace to convert timestamp in such form:

```
2020-06-20T17:25:59:378Z
```

The following code will convert it to seconds

```
unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(value,'(.*?)T(.*?):([^:]*?)Z$','$1 $2\\.$3'))
```

I have other two timestamps that I wish to convert to seconds, such as:

```
2020-03-19 15:45:33
03-19-2020 11:07:25:103
```

How should I convert these two timestamp to seconds by using regexp_replace() or any other functions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `unix_timestamp` returns seconds passed from unix epoch. It does ignore milliseconds. This is why if you want epoch time in seconds, you can  extract only `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`.

Second, If you have all these different formats in single dataset and you want to convert them all, you can use case statement to check pattern and convert accordingly:

```
with your_data as ( --This is your data example
select stack(3,
             '2020-06-20T17:25:59:378Z',
             '2020-03-19 15:45:33',
             '03-19-2020 11:07:25:103'
            ) as str
)

select case when str rlike '^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})[T ](\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})' --matches first two strings
             then unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(str,'^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})[T ](\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})','$1 $2'))
            when str rlike '^(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4})[T ](\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})' --matches third string, allows T or space after date
             then unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(str,'^(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4})[T ](\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})','$3-$1-$2 $4'))
        end result_unix_timestamp
from your_data
```

Returns:

```
result_unix_timestamp
1592673959
1584632733
1584616045
```

You can add more patterns to the case with corresponding conversion and in such way convert all possible cases. And of course, not necessarily all cases should use regex_replace for conversion. Though regex allows to identify and parse most complex strings.

Also you can try to convert using one pattern and if it returns `null` then try to convert using another pattern and so on:

```
coalesce(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(str,'^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})[T ](\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})','$1 $2')),
         unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(str,'^(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4})[T ](\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})','$3-$1-$2 $4'))
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first one you really do not need to use regex_replace.

```
select unix_timestamp('2020-06-20T17:25:59:378Z','yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
```

And the other two

```
select unix_timestamp('2020-03-19 15:45:33', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
select unix_timestamp('03-19-2020 11:07:25:103', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS');
```

Comment: I applied the code, but the outcomes are all null...

Comment: Actually, I retried only 2020-06-20T17:25:59:378Z is not working the others worked